# How to pass data from Modal pop-up to parent page

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I could not solve Reactive Forms from modal pop-up to parent component properly. I'm trying to pass an data in empty array from modal pop-up to parent component. I got an data in console. But, I need an data need to display in Parent page.  Kindly help me out with the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a look at this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: things to consider when updating your question. What component library are you using? Angular Material, prime-ng, something else? It would be good to mention that and provide your code as an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Could you please provide code with issue or unfinished code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.